# Python + Jinja2 displaying data from json

Tags: python, json, jinja2

I am trying to build a basic site to list podcast episodes. Data about the episodes is stored in a single json file (there are not many episodes yet).

I am using Python and Jinja2 to build the site. However, I am running into a not especially helpful error message when I try to render the page, passing the decoded json as a parameter.

http://pod.luketimoth.me/site/index.py This will show the error: `dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 7; 2 is required` which I don't find especially helpful. What is a dictionary update sequence? Why is element #0 *required* to be of size 2? Surely it can be whatever size I define it to be?

The json file is stored here: http://pod.luketimoth.me/site/data/episodes.json

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Turns out the Json file cannot be just an anonymous array. I had to wrap the array in an object first. As you will see if you click the link to the json file.